# How do I define a gallery of inline content in HTML for use with Magnific-Popup ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magnific-popup

I have many galleries on a page which are launched from their respective buttons. I like the idea of defining the markup for the galleries in the page alongside the button and then hiding using the `.mfp-hide`. However I cannot get the popup to activate when I add the `delegate` keyword (it does otherwise).

Here is the code I have so far,

HTML

```
<div id="gallery1" class="mfp-hide">
  <div class="slide">
    ... some content for slide 1 ...
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    ... some content for slide 2 ...
  </div>
</div>

<p>Blah blah <a href="#gallery1" class="open-gallery-link">view gallery one</a> blah blah ...</p>
```

Javascript

```
$('.open-gallery-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  delegate:'.slide',
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't work this way, `delegate` is always looking for children of target DOM element (in your case children of element `.open-gallery-link`).

You may just parse everything via jQuery and open gallery via API:

```
$('.open-gallery-link').click(function() {

  var items = [];
  $( $(this).attr('href') ).find('.slide').each(function() {
    items.push( {
      src: $(this) 
    } );
  });

  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items:items,
    gallery: {
      enabled: true 
    }
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/zvLny

Comment: Ah thanks, that is brilliant. I reasoned that if the activating DOM element (i.e. the `a` element in this case) pointed to another element (e.g. through the `href`) the target DOM element would be substituted for the one referred to in the `href` attribute. Still this way works just great - thanks again and great plugin!