# Simple Magnific Popup Gallery not working

Tags: magnific-popup

I tried this simple example:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
gallery: {
  enabled: true
},
items: [
  {src: "tracks/" + p[0]},
  {src: "tracks/" + p[1]}
],
type: 'image'
});
```

Only the first slide (0) pops up and there is no gallery - just a single slide. What is wrong?

Comment: I think I give up with this one. I have tried other solutions (including [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067062/how-do-i-define-a-gallery-of-inline-content-in-html-for-use-with-magnific-popup)) but gallery will not work. Magnific Popup works fine for single slides but not for gallery. I don't know what the problem is. Could jQM be a problem? I have probably missed something? Meanwhile I will go for Colorbox - works without any problems...

Answer (score 2):

You should never give up: Problem is solved. I isolated the code from the gallery example of the homepage of Magnific Popup and put it into a page of my own. The result was the same as described above i.e. gallery was not working. I then downloaded Magnific Popup again and noticed that the library file was bigger than my previous library file. So the library file was corrupted in some way - probably my fault. Now gallery is working...